# Why use .call vs just adding methods directly to prototype?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

There's a Node.js plugin I'm using which implements a pattern that I'd like to better understand.

```
var Thing = function() {};

(function () {

    this.foo = function() {};
    this.bar = function() {}

}).call(Thing.prototype);
```

I understand that [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is calling the anonymous function with the Thing.prototype context. Does that mean that `this.foo` is actually being added to Thing's prototype? That's the part that is a little foggy for me if someone could explain.

Also, what would be the advantage of this approach as opposed to just:

```
Thing.prototype.foo = function() {};
Thing.prototype.bar = function() {};
```

Comment: I'm with you - I think your second syntax is a bit clearer; the first seems silly to me.  Or maybe a Pointy or Felix King can come along and enlighten us :)

Comment: Do `foo` and `bar` depend on local variables created in the anonymous function?

Comment: @user2357112 nope, there are no local vars in the anon function.

Comment: Are there any variables/functions within the anonymous function that the methods are using?  If so, then the instance methods are acting as closures with private access to some functions/objects.  That's one use-case in which this pattern would make sense.

Comment: *"Does that mean that this.foo is actually being added to Thing's prototype?"* Yes, it does.

Comment: What @Steve said - you *must* have left out some details.

Comment: @Steve that makes sense. There are none in this case, but perhaps that answers where the pattern came from. Maybe he was leaving himself the option.

Comment: *" what would be the advantage of this approach"* Perhaps brevity if there are many additions, though it would be shorter without `.call()` and `this`. Perhaps someone just trying to be clever?

Comment: It's just a clever way to pass in the prototype as the IIFE's scope.

Comment: There's also the possibility that the code is generated from a code generator like TypeScript or something. Sometimes there are patterns used that aren't strictly needed for a given circumstance.

Comment: *what would be the advantage of this approach as opposed to just [adding directly to Thing.prototype]* —the only one I can think if is that you can assign to `this.foo` rather than `Thing.prototype.foo`, so maybe a few less characters to type, but not many. Otherwise, there are zero benefits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
(function () {

    this.foo = function() {};
    this.bar = function() {}

}).call(Thing.prototype);
```

`call(Thing.prototype)` causes the value of `this` inside the anonymous function to be `Thing.prototype` so it is setting fields on `Thing.prototype`. See the documentation for [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), but basically the first argument given to `call` sets the value of `this` for the function being called, and then the remaining arguments are whatever parameters the function takes. So the code above adds the fields `foo` and `bar` to `Thing.prototype`.

This style of setting fields would allow you to readily declare variables inside the closure if you wanted to. For instance:

```
(function () {

    var _foo = 0;

    this.foo = function() {
        return _foo;
    };

    this.bar = function() {
        _foo++;
    }

}).call(Thing.prototype);
```

The `_foo` variable cannot be directly accessed by anything else than the methods.

It is largely a matter of preference what style one uses. I prefer to use 2nd style in the question:

```
Thing.prototype.foo = ...
```

This is mainly because some of the tools I use work better with it. (jsdoc in particular.) And I prefer having ready access to all the fields of my objects.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern in the OP is the same as using:

```
(function () {

    Thing.prototype.foo = function() {};
    Thing.prototype.bar = function() {}

})();
```

But that is only useful if the enclosing function expression creates useful closures (per Louis' answer).

I suppose the *call* version is a few less characters to type and makes it simpler to change from *Thing.prototype* to *someOtherThing.prototype*.